# Display a Fragment element inside a Dialog element

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app the same functionality should be shared between different device-oriented layouts. For handsets, I've got an activity for performing some transactions - simultaneously I've got to implement the same functionality within a popup for tablet version.

So far I've tried putting fragment into dialog both ways: statically and dynamically. When I do it statically it moans about duplicate ID and I guess this means that Fragment is already created. On the other hand when I try to implement it dynamically it says that there's no view for the fragment. I do it like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(_layoutResID);


}

@Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        TabletLoginFragment loginFragment = new TabletLoginFragment();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.login_fragment_holder, loginFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Both ways I can't get it working - what would you recommend to place fragment inside of a Dialog element ?

Comment: Why dont u use activity with "dialog theme" and try the same. Though I think fragments inside a dialog interface isn't a very good thing!

Comment: nice suggestion, gonna look into it